# At what point in the View lifecycle should I unsubscribe if the View is never made visible?

Tags: android, android-view, rx-java, rx-android

I have a View that converts some text to a localised version of that text using an API. This works if the View is visible in the layout because once the View gets destroy `onDetachedFromWindow()` gets called. However if the View is invisible and never gets attached to the Window `onDetachedFromWindow()` never gets called.

I tried performing the localisation in `onAttachedToWindow()` but this ends up causing the Text to not be displayed/cut off.

```
public class LocalisedTextView extends TextView {

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        setLocalisedText(label);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
            subscription = null;
        }
    }

    public void setLocalisedText(String label) {
        if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
            subscription = null;
        }

        subscription = localisationService.get(label)
                .observeOn(Scheduler.ui())
                .subscribe(this::setText;    
    }
}
```

This causes a memory leak in the case where the View is never made visible/put onto the Window.

So I was wondering what the best approach would be to handle subscriptions on Views that may never be attached to the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A graphical element like a view should not be performing any logic that doesn't directly effect drawing.  It should not be localizing text, instead localized text should be passed in to it.

Comment: Thanks, I had been thinking about the problem the wrong way. I'm creating a sort of Localisation Manager that is aware of the Activity/Fragment lifecycle (using a LifecycleEvent Observable) and manages the localised views.

Comment: I don't agree with this logic. It makes sense to put this repeatable behavior inside the TextView, the same way it makes sense to put the image downloading logic inside an ImageView if you're always having URLs.

What you were missing was that your localisationService.get(label) was calling `onNext` on the subscriber i.e. your view, but it should've also called the `onCompleted` which would've closed the subscription and there would've been no memory leaks.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for an image view either- why should a graphical component be doing http requests? Should it include an ftp module add well? Gopher? No, all of that stuff should be outside and feed into the class